# How to Extract SceneKit Depth Buffer at runtime in AR scene?

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, depth-buffer

How does one extract the SceneKit depth buffer? I make an AR based app that is running Metal and I'm really struggling to find any info on how to extract a 2D depth buffer so I can render out fancy 3D photos of my scenes.  Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is unclear but I'll try to answer.

### Depth pass from VR view

If you need to render a Depth pass from SceneKit's 3D environment then you should use, for instance, a [SCNGeometrySource.Semantic](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scngeometrysource/semantic) structure. There are `vertex`, `normal`, `texcoord`, `color` and `tangent` type properties. Let's see what a `vertex` type property is:

```
static let vertex: SCNGeometrySource.Semantic
```

> This semantic identifies data containing the positions of each vertex in the geometry. For a custom shader program, you use this semantic to bind SceneKit’s vertex position data to an input attribute of the shader. Vertex position data is typically an array of three- or four-component vectors.

Here's a code's excerpt from [iOS Depth Sample](https://github.com/shu223/iOS-Depth-Sampler/blob/master/iOS-Depth-Sampler/Samples/PointCloud/PointCloud.swift) project.

**UPDATED:** Using this code you can get a position for every point in SCNScene and assign a color for these points (this is what a zDepth channel really is):

```
import SceneKit

struct PointCloudVertex {
    var x: Float, y: Float, z: Float
    var r: Float, g: Float, b: Float
}

@objc class PointCloud: NSObject {
    
    var pointCloud : [SCNVector3] = []
    var colors: [UInt8] = []
    
    public func pointCloudNode() -> SCNNode {
        let points = self.pointCloud
        var vertices = Array(repeating: PointCloudVertex(x: 0,
                                                         y: 0,
                                                         z: 0,
                                                         r: 0,
                                                         g: 0,
                                                         b: 0), 
                                                     count: points.count)
        
        for i in 0...(points.count-1) {
            let p = points[i]
            vertices[i].x = Float(p.x)
            vertices[i].y = Float(p.y)
            vertices[i].z = Float(p.z)
            vertices[i].r = Float(colors[i * 4]) / 255.0
            vertices[i].g = Float(colors[i * 4 + 1]) / 255.0
            vertices[i].b = Float(colors[i * 4 + 2]) / 255.0
        }
        
        let node = buildNode(points: vertices)
        return node
    }
    
    private func buildNode(points: [PointCloudVertex]) -> SCNNode {
        let vertexData = NSData(
            bytes: points,
            length: MemoryLayout<PointCloudVertex>.size * points.count
        )
        let positionSource = SCNGeometrySource(
            data: vertexData as Data,
            semantic: SCNGeometrySource.Semantic.vertex,
            vectorCount: points.count,
            usesFloatComponents: true,
            componentsPerVector: 3,
            bytesPerComponent: MemoryLayout<Float>.size,
            dataOffset: 0,
            dataStride: MemoryLayout<PointCloudVertex>.size
        )
        let colorSource = SCNGeometrySource(
            data: vertexData as Data,
            semantic: SCNGeometrySource.Semantic.color,
            vectorCount: points.count,
            usesFloatComponents: true,
            componentsPerVector: 3,
            bytesPerComponent: MemoryLayout<Float>.size,
            dataOffset: MemoryLayout<Float>.size * 3,
            dataStride: MemoryLayout<PointCloudVertex>.size
        )
        let element = SCNGeometryElement(
            data: nil,
            primitiveType: .point,
            primitiveCount: points.count,
            bytesPerIndex: MemoryLayout<Int>.size
        )

        element.pointSize = 1
        element.minimumPointScreenSpaceRadius = 1
        element.maximumPointScreenSpaceRadius = 5

        let pointsGeometry = SCNGeometry(sources: [positionSource, colorSource], elements: [element])
        
        return SCNNode(geometry: pointsGeometry)
    }
}
```

### Depth pass from AR view

If you need to render a Depth pass from ARSCNView it is possible only in case you're using [ARFaceTrackingConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arfacetrackingconfiguration) for the front-facing camera. If so, then you can employ [capturedDepthData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/2928208-captureddepthdata) instance property that brings you a depth map, captured along with the video frame.

```
var capturedDepthData: AVDepthData? { get }
```

***But this depth map image is `only 15 fps and of lower resolution` than corresponding RGB image at 60 fps***.

> Face-based AR uses the front-facing, depth-sensing camera on compatible devices. When running such a configuration, frames vended by the session contain a depth map captured by the depth camera in addition to the color pixel buffer (see [capturedImage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/2867984-capturedimage)) captured by the color camera. This property’s value is always nil when running other AR configurations.

And a real code could be like this:

```
extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate {
    
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
        
        DispatchQueue.global().async {

            guard let frame = self.sceneView.session.currentFrame else {
                return
            }
            if let depthImage = frame.capturedDepthData {
                self.depthImage = (depthImage as! CVImageBuffer)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Depth pass from Video view

Also, you can extract a true Depth pass using 2 back-facing cameras and `AVFoundation` framework.

Look at [Image Depth Map](https://www.raywenderlich.com/314-image-depth-maps-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started) tutorial where **Disparity** concept will be introduced to you.

Comment: Thanks for such a broad answer!  I'm just after the depth buffer for the 3D opjects I'm passing into my back facing camera's feed - so that would be your first option? It's a bit of an ask, but if you could clarify that option a little bit further *please* - the other two techniques seem rather well documented out there, however my need, which I expected would be quite a normal request isn't.  I just need a grey scale UIImage or even CVImage etc, happy to resize if necessary to match my RGB buffer I'm capturing. Thanks.

Comment: To be precise, what do you need exactly: DepthPass from SceneKit (for virtual objects) or DepthPass from ARSCNView (for real world objects)? Or both?

Comment: Only virtual objects, my phone is too old for both unfortunately.

Comment: I updated my answer. There's a link to real `depth-channel-extraction` project. You can find there all features you're looking for.

Comment: I'm trying be concise, but I'm only needing the virtual objects! - it's still going to be a great answer for every way though! Eg, just getting my runtime added geo's depth. So sorry, and really appreciate your answers. -- just compiling now, but the Readme.md seems to just be for the camera view and not the virtual objects.

Comment: A code in my updated answer is for extracting zChannel for `virtual objects`. It's not a ready application or ready-to-use solution, it's a starting point for implementation.